# How can I watch and compile multiple coffeescript files simultaneously?

Tags: coffeescript

Check out this little `watch.sh` script

```
coffee -j main.js -cw javascripts/*.coffee
coffee -j controllers.js -cw javascripts/controllers/*.coffee
```

That will only actually watch the first folder (`javascripts/*.coffee`).

How can I watch both, and compile the results into two different .js-files? (main.js and controllers.js)

Desired result:

- All .coffee files in javascripts/ should be compiled into main.js
- All .coffee files in javascripts/controllers should be compiled into controllers.js

Edit:
I've solved this by creating a simple executable that does this:

```
coffee -j wingme.js -cw javascripts/*.coffee &
coffee -j controllers.js -cw javascripts/controllers/*.coffee &
```

It will watch both folders in the background. Please let me know if you've got a better approach!

Comment: Grunt is another approach, but the `&` method is what I'm going for right now...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple executable that watches both directories.

```
coffee -j wingme.js -cw javascripts/*.coffee &
coffee -j controllers.js -cw javascripts/controllers/*.coffee &
```

It will watch both folders in the background.